# Add "last update" of day and time in Android studio (Java). From Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to implement "last updated on ..... at ....." writing. How can I recover this data from Firestore?
Each document must have its own. And with each change it will have to be updated.

Thank you

I try to search for this but i've to found anithing

Comment: What have you tried in code?

Comment: You need to do this manually in firestore, There is no default way to do this, you can update two param every time when you update any document, Thanks

Comment: I would update the last update as server-side date: like `docRef.update("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp())` or you if you want you can replace the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` with your own time. take a look at this docs: 
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-server-timestamp#firestore_data_set_server_timestamp-java